# Excel VBA Converting seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to convert specific data in a specific column through the whole worksheet.

This is my current code, it does not error out, however it doesn't display the first result correctly (Shows 00:00:00), and only stops at the first record.

```
Sub CleanEntry()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Seconds As Integer
    Dim j As Long
Dim c As Long
j = 2

For i = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
c = Range("B" & j).Value
c = c / 86400
Range("B" & j).Value = Format(c, "hh:mm:ss")
j = j + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Since `c` is long, you are losing a fair amount of information with `c = c / 86400`

Comment: Store it as a double perhaps?

Comment: Long is like integer in that it will remove the decimal.  And since time is a decimal it removing the time completely.  So yes make it a Double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I do not understand why you are using two counters, with one going backwards and the other forward, this can be done with one line:

```
Sub CleanEntry()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

j = 2

For i = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Range("B" & j).Value = Format(TimeSerial(0, 0, Range("B" & j).Value), "hh:mm:ss")
    j = j + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This solved the issue completely. I did not think of TimeSerial at all. Thanks!